Derivation of Euler Equation in presence of the Dixit-Stiglitz Aggregator
I reading the working paper of Sebastian Banz (2012). I have an issue with the derivation of the Euler equation.
The author models the demand side of the economy as follows
The representative consumer has the following intertemporal utility function:
\begin{equation}
W = \int_{0}^{\infty} U(t) e^{-\rho t} dt
\end{equation}
where $\rho$ is the discount factor.
Then, utility in each period is given by
\begin{equation}
U(t) = \left( \int_{0}^{N(t)} x_j (t)^{\frac{\sigma -1}{\sigma}} \, dj \right)^{\frac{\sigma}{\sigma-1}}
\end{equation}
where $x_j(t)$ denotes the consumption of variety $j$ at time $t$.
Then, the demand function implied by the intratemporal utility maximization reads
\begin{equation}
x_j(t) = \frac{E(t) p_j (t)^{-\sigma}}{\int_{0}^{N(t)} p_j(t)^{1 -\sigma}dj }
\end{equation}
where $p_j(t)$ is the price of variety $j$ at time $t$.
The intertemporal budget constraint reads
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-rt} E(t) dt \le \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-rt} w(t) dt + A(t)
\end{equation}
where $E(t)$ denotes consumer expenditure and $A(t)$ the value of assets at period $t$.
Then, the author claims that maximizing $(1)$ s.t. $(4)$ gives the following Euler equation: $\frac{\dot{E}}{E} = r - \rho$.
I cannot find it. Let me show you why:
First, I define the aggregate price index as $P(t) \equiv \left[ \int_{0}^{N(t)} p_j(t)^{1-\sigma} dj \right]^{\frac{1}{1-\sigma}}$.
Thus, the demand function from equation $(3)$ reads
\begin{equation}
x_j(t) = E(t) p_j(t)^{- \sigma} P(t)^{- (1- \sigma)}
\end{equation}
and substituting this into the instantaneous utility function (eq. 2) gives
\begin{equation}
U(t) = E(t)/P(t)
\end{equation}
and plugging this into equation one and setting up the Hamiltonian, I have:
\begin{equation}
H = e^{- \rho t} \frac{E(t)}{P(t)} + \lambda(t) \left[ e^{-rt} w(t) + A(t) - e^{-rt} E(t) \right] 
\end{equation}
where $\lambda$ is my costate variable.
Then, the FOCs are: $H_E =0$ and $H_A = - \dot{\lambda}$
The issue arises from the first first-order condition (FOC), where I lose $E(t)$, rendering it impossible for me to derive the author's Euler equation. Do you agree? I believe the author should have used the following utility function, employing log utility:
\begin{equation}
W = \int_{0}^{\infty} log[U(t)] e^{-\rho t} dt
\end{equation}
And also, the intertemporal budget constraint seems to be wrong. It should be
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-rt} E(t) dt + \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-rt} A(t) dt \le \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-rt} w(t) dt + A(0)
\end{equation}
However, I still have problems with this. The next one allows me to find the classical Euler equation
\begin{equation}
\dot{A}(t)= r(t)A(t) + w(t) - E(t)
\end{equation}
